# How to calculate Digest Value of hmax sha1 encryption

Tags: php, sha1

Hi i have to send data on an api using Curl. It requires digest value in the request header. But i am getting the error of Signature Mismatch in the response of the Curl.

Here are the steps to create the Digest Value:

For calculating the Digest value Please follow below Steps:

1) Get an hmac_sha1 key from the raw key bytes (Here raw key bytes will be the Client_secret (will be shared on
phone)

2) Compute the hmac on Payload bytes

3) Hex-encode the hmac(Hex encode instead of Base64 as mentioned in Example) and return the string obtained is the DigestValue

4) The algorithm used is: HmacSHA1

Please refer Example 50 on below link for more help: http://www.javatips.net/api/java.security.signatureexception

Hex encode instead of Base64 as mentioned in Example, Here Client_secret to be used instead of key as mentioned
in example

### I tried to create the digest value using this code:

```
$key=rrxfwr@*QB60rrxfwr@*QB60;
$client_secret='EghAfDrNv4RrGpRvbH1/00BGiC3vCP49cwVAEIzT7ob5JFiEQS5oMg==';
$pad=hash_hmac("sha1",$client_secret,true);
$digestvalue=bin2hex($pad);
```

Comment: have you tried to base64 decode the payload before doing the hmac?

Comment: @Ja͢ck you mean before converting it to bin2hex?

Comment: @Ja͢ck just tried still not working

Comment: @Ja͢ck i get this kind of value if i base64 decode payload @|:Ϳ�k�ol}�@F�-��=s@����$X�A.h2

Comment: @Ja͢ck i have edited the question with few more details. Can you help me out

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual and from your description, it should be this:

```php
$key = 'rrxfwr@*QB60rrxfwr@*QB60';
$data = base64_decode('EghAfDrNv4RrGpRvbH1/00BGiC3vCP49cwVAEIzT7ob5JFiEQS5oMg==');
$pad = hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $key, true);
$digestvalue = bin2hex($pad);
```

It seems that you had the arguments for `$data` and `$key` in reverse.